# when you work on a DAO Recordset is the databse updated live?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using

```
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MyDB")
```

and

```
Do Until rs.EOF
```

to do operation on each line of a database and creating entries in a field. During the process I check values against the database using Dcount and Dlookup to see if a that value already exist and make decisions based on that. 
When done with the line I update the DB using `rs1.update` and move to the next line.
My questions is When I do `rs1.update` will the changes I made in the record be already taken in account in the database when I go to the next line and do another Dcount and Dlookup ?

Comment: I think so, yes. If in doubt, after moving to the next record, check the previous record.

Answer (score 0):

*Update* commits the change. So: Yes.